# What is the significance of Planck units?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, absolute-units

There are many questions asked about different Planck units.

This question is just a generalization of all of those questions.

Planck units are considered to be natural units. The thing I don't understand that why Planck length and Planck time and Planck energy are considered very important where other Planck units are very arbitrary. I have searched on many websites and wherever I go I see people claiming that beyond the Planck length ,the concept of legth becomes meaningless ,even popular physicists claim that. But when I go to the Wikipedia page for Planck length, it says that Planck length might not be the smallest possible length.

I just used Planck length as an example.

But my question is that what is the significance of Planck units?

Comment: In what sense are other Planck units “very arbitrary”?

Comment: As an example planck units defines mass now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All Planck units are constructed from $c$, $\hbar$, and $G$. The speed of light $c$ is the defining constant of Special Relativity. Planck’s constant is the defining constant of quantum mechanics. Newton’s gravitational constant $G$ is the defining constant of gravity.

Thus any theory which brings together Special Relativity, quantum mechanics, and gravity is going to presumably involve Planck units. The constants going in to such a theory are going to come out in Planck combinations when you calculate something, based on nothing deeper than dimensional analysis.

(But perhaps there will be surprises such as huge dimensionless factors throwing all the Planck scales dramatically off! As a made-up example, suppose spacetime quanta, if such things exist, are not on the Planck scale but a factor of $e^{\pi/\alpha}$ smaller, where $\alpha$ is a small fundamental unified coupling constant similar to the fine-structure constant of electromagnetism. Can you see what a huge difference that would make? And what it would mean for trying to test the theory experimentally?)

No theory unifying Special Relativity, quantum mechanics, and gravity currently has wide acceptance, so the actual physical significance of Planck units is unclear. People talk about things like “spacetime foam” or “spacetime quanta” at (around) the Planck length and time scales, string-theory particles with masses at (around) the Planck mass or higher, possible unification of all forces at (around) the Planck energy, black holes containing Planck stars having (around) the Planck density, and the like. But in the absence of an accepted theory of relativistic quantum gravity, all these things are speculative. They can be exciting, fascinating, and beautiful ideas, but alas they are speculative.

They have been speculative for all of my life, and I expect that they will remain speculative for all of yours. (I am old enough to remember the “first superstring revolution” in 1984. Here we are 36 years later. Lots of interesting progress, but no accepted theory of relativistic quantum gravity, using strings or anything else.) But I would love to be wrong about this!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the principal significance of Planck Units is the [nondimensionalization of all equations in physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondimensionalization) so that every quantitative expression of physical quantity is simply a pure number with no unit attached and would be the same quantity that anyone else in the Universe would measure in experiment or derive in theory.

In my opinion, Planck Units (as any other unit system) should be *"rationalized Planck units"*.  These units would result in these four dimensionful scaling factors to be set to one:

$$\begin{align}
c &= 1 \\
\hbar &= 1 \\
4 \pi G &= 1 \\
\epsilon_0 &= 1 \\
\end{align} $$

Specifically, in terms of any other system of units, these **Rationalized Planck Units** are:

$\begin{align}
\text{natural unit of time:} \qquad \qquad t_\mathrm{p} &= \sqrt{\frac{\hbar \, 4\pi G}{c^5}} \\
\\
\text{natural unit of length:} \qquad \qquad \ell_\mathrm{p} &= \sqrt{\frac{\hbar \, 4\pi G}{c^3}} \\
\\
\text{natural unit of mass:} \qquad \qquad m_\mathrm{p} &= \sqrt{\frac{\hbar \, c}{4\pi G}} \\
\\
\text{natural unit of electric charge:} \qquad \qquad q_\mathrm{p} &= \sqrt{\epsilon_0 \hbar c} \\
\end{align} $

The difference between this definition and the original Planck definition is that for **both** EM and gravitational radiation, the speed of the wavefront in a vacuum ($c$) ***and*** the characteristic impedance of radiation in vacuo ($\frac{1}{\epsilon_0 c}$ for EM or $\frac{4 \pi G}{c}$ for gravitational radiation) are normalized to $1$.  Equivalently, what this rationalized definition does is completely equate the concepts of field strength and flux density in free space.

[There's a little bit more about this that I wrote in another answer.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/694192/is-the-exact-definition-of-the-planck-units-important/778966#778966)  I think that it's important that, when considering the deepest cosmological questions and models, why things are like they are, what is truly universal and fundamental and what is  colored specifically by ***our*** human experience (anthropocentrism, anthropometric perceptions), that rationalized Planck Units be used everywhere.  Then that completely obviates any human consideration of the *"specialness"* of the values of the speed of light (and speed of any other "instantaneous" interaction), Planck's, Newton's, and Coulomb's constants.  Sometimes people speculate about the time variation of those constants, which are not attached to ***any*** object in the Universe but are ***only*** anthropometric expressions of parameters intrinsic to the Universe.  All those parameters need to be are **real**, **positive**, and **finite**.  Then it doesn't matter what their value is, we can always describe reality as if their values are equal to $1$ and whatever else we measure in experiment or describe in theory are ***dimensionless*** values and the same for us as they would be for the aliens living on the planet Zog, ***unless*** physical reality is different on Zog than here on Earth.

So it makes no sense, whatsoever, to be asking *"what if the speed of light is different on Zog than it is here?"*  But it **does** make sense to ask *"what if the [fine-structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant) or the [proton mass to electron mass ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton-to-electron_mass_ratio) are different on Zog than they are here?"*  The latter are meaningful questions as would be the measure of some property of a particle or universal object in terms of (rationalized) Planck units.  All these questions are about dimensionless values that will be the same anywhere else in the Universe, ***unless*** physical reality is different there than it is here.

That's what the most fundamental significance of Planck units are about.